# Is it always possible for every point of a Hausdorff space to find a not constant sequence that converges to that point?

Tags: sequences-and-series, general-topology

I just have a ***X*** Hausdorff space such that a single point can't be an open set (for example X is not discrete) and a given point x $\in$ X. My idea was to construct a sequence a<sub>n</sub> $\subset$ X and U<sub>n</sub> $\subset$ P(X) of open sets such that a<sub>n</sub> $\in$ U<sub>n</sub>, x $\in$ U<sub>n</sub> $\forall$n and U<sub>n+1</sub> = U<sub>n</sub> $\cap$ V, where V is an open set such that x $\in$ V and a<sub>n</sub> $\notin$ V (which exists since X is a Hausdorff space). The problem is that I'm not sure if I can define a sequence like this (maybe is axiom of choice required?), and I don't either know if this sequence actually converges to x. Is there a simpler succession (if it's exists)? Thank you

Comment: What if $X$ is discrete? (I'm assuming you're looking for a sequence which isn't just not constant but also not eventually constant)

Comment: @MorA. Yes, you're right: I forgot to say that X is a topological space such that a single point can't be an open set, I'm sorry: I'll edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not always possible. The construction you suggest will only work if the point has a countable neighbourhood base. A standard counterexample is the extended long ray ($\omega_1 + 1$ with each point joined to its successor by a copy of an open interval, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Long_line_(topology) ). No sequence (unless eventually constant) can converge to the end-point $\omega_1$.

Comment: Another counter example would be extremally disconnected Hausdorff spaces, as in an extremally disconnected space all converging sequences have to be eventually constant.